# Programa que ler 3 números com estrutura de repetição com a classe scanner!

Tags: java, loop, matemática

Como fazer um algoritmo em Java que lê 3 números e dá a média? Eu sei fazer sem usar estrutura de repetição, mas como fazer com estrutura de repetição?

Segue meu código abaixo, porem não tem o resultado esperado:

```
    public class NotaAluno {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        int notaAluno[] = new int[3];
        int i;
        double media = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < notaAluno.length; i++){
            System.out.println("Informe o numero da nota do aluno [" + notaAluno[i]+"]" );
            notaAluno[i] = entrada.nextInt(); 
            media = (notaAluno.length)/ 3;
        }
        System.out.println("A Media dos alunos eh " + media);
    }
}
```

Comment: Já tentei fazer dessa forma ´media = (notaAluno[i]) / 3´ porem sem sucesso

Comment: Precisa de vetor mesmo pra isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem vários erros (que eu consertei), mas o problema maior é que está tentando calcular a média dentro do laço, tem que achar o total e depois calcular a média:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class NotaAluno {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        int notaAluno[] = new int[3];
        int total = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < notaAluno.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Informe o numero da nota do aluno [" + i + "]" );
            notaAluno[i] = entrada.nextInt(); 
            total += notaAluno[i];
        }
        System.out.println("A Media dos alunos eh " + total / 3);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/nfwwVr). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/dlfufqil-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Algorithm/GetData2.java).

Se não for fazer nada com os valores o *array* está sendo criado sem necessidade. ´Só para calcular a média não precisa guardar valor individual.

Comment: bigown♦ voce mencionou isso: "Se não for fazer nada com os valores o array está sendo criado sem necessidade" poderia me explicar? obg desde já.

Comment: Qualquer coisa que você use, você tem que explicar o uso. Se você não tem uma explicação para o uso, não deve usar, simples assim. Nesse caso ele não está sendo usado para nada, então não tem porque colocar aí.

Comment: Obrigado acho que entendi hehehe